# How can I prove this language is not regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

$$\left\{a^{2^n}\mid n \ge 0\right\} \subset \{a\}^*$$

How can I prove this language is not regular?

Comment: What does `a 2 n` mean?  Did you mean $a^{2n}$?  (If so, you can't, because that language is regular.)  or did you mean $a^{2^n}$?

Comment: [How to type mathematical formulas on this web site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Apologies, edited for correct formatting

Comment: Either the [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) or the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) will do the job fairly easily; are you familiar with either of them?

Comment: I have been trying to use pumping lemma but have never used it before, I was trying to look for an example using this question

Comment: In this particular case, just looking at the _length_ strings is enough. The pumping lemma gives you one subset of strings in the language (if it is regular) with a certain relationship between the lengths of consecutive members of that subset; the description of the set tells you something about the lengths of strings too. If you can show a contradiction between these two descriptions, the language is not regular.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the language is regular, then there is a DFA for it with $n$ states. Then for the strings $a^{2^i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n + 1$ at least 2 of them must be in the same accept state by the pigeonhole principle. Say that the two strings are $a^{2^j}$ and $a^{2^k}$ with $j < k$. Since they are in the same state, so long as we append the same string to both of them, they should still go to the same state in the DFA. Can you find a string to append such that one of them should be accepted whereas the other one is not?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the language is regular, and let $p$ be the pumping length. Consider the word $w=a^{2^p}$; $2^p\ge p$, so the pumping lemma says that $w$ can be decomposed as $xyz$ in such a way that $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz$ is in the language for every $k\ge 0$. There must be integers $r,s$, and $t$ such that $x=a^r$, $y=a^s$, and $z=a^t$, where $s\ge 1$, and $r+s+t=2^p$.

Now suppose that $k\ge 0$; what does $xy^kz$ look like? It must be

$$a^r(a^s)^ka^t=a^ra^{ks}a^r=a^{r+ks+t}=a^{2^p+(k-1)s}\;.$$

To get your contradiction, you need only show that there must be some $k\ge 0$ such that $2^p+(k-1)s$  is not a power of $2$.

HINT: $\langle 2^p+(k-1)s:k\ge 0\rangle$ is an arithmetic sequence: adjacent terms are $s$ units apart. The powers of $2$, on the other hand, get further and further apart as the exponent increases.

Comment: how can i prove that some 2^p+(k−1)s is not a power of 2 when only filling the k variable?

Comment: @sam: Think a bit more about the hint that I gave; it contains the key idea. If you keep increasing in steps of size $s$, you have to hit numbers that are between powers of $2$, because after a certain point all powers of $2$ are more than $s$ units apart.

Comment: You lost me very early on in your answer, around where you mention integers r,s and t. I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @sam: I'm simply applying the pumping lemma. Each of the pieces $x,y$, and $z$ must be a string of $a$s; $r,s$, and $t$ are the numbers of $a$s in $x,y$, and $z$, respectively. They must add up to $2^p$, since that's the length of $w$, and the pumping lemma requires that $s$ be at least $1$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "Pumping lemma" you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem and show that $a^{2^n}$ and $a^{2^m}$ are in different classes of equivalence if $n\ne m$.